# Inlining failed: function body can be overwritten at link time

Tags: c++, g++

I upgraded today from Ubuntu 12.04 which I think had g++-4.6 to Ubuntu 12.10 with g++-4.7.2. In my code I had a few functions marked as `__attribute__((always_inline))`. The reason for this was simply that profiling showed me that it increased the performance of the code significantly. It worked fine with g++ 4.6 but now with g++ 4.7 I get the error message:

> error: inlining failed in call to always_inline 'void func_name(args)': function body can be overwritten at link time

I can't share my actual code, I've tried to narrow it down but when I change too much the error goes away, so that's not helpful. I'm interested in the root cause of this error message.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It wasn't my intention to answer this myself, but I accidentally found the answer a few minutes after I had posted.

The reason for this (cryptic) error message was that the function was not marked as `inline`, only `__attribute((always_inline))`.

Comment: By replacing __attribute((always_inline)) with inline, you just silenced the compiler. Your function is most probably not inlined.

Comment: I didn't replace it, I added "inline" in addition to "__attribute((always_inline))"

Answer (score 0):

For us, the issue was that we failed to also declare the function "static".  "**attribute**((always_inline))" means, in plain text, "inline this and never include a function body" and the error message means "the compiler had to include a function body".  In our case, since the function wasn't "static", it needed to be available for an external reference.